# How to unchain items in list<t> class

Tags: c#, winforms, list, class

can some one explain to me how to break the chain with a NEW statement?

Let me clarify the chain I’m talking about. When I call to a class I use the NEW statement like so

```
Myclass x =new Myclass();
```

My understanding is this creates a new empty instance of Myclass. Now correct me if I’m wrong but having a new empty instance one should be able to add what ever data the class supports?

I use this lot and would think the above to be true until adding data in such a manner

```
Myclass x =new Myclass();

//oldMyclass being old data that needs to be changed then 
//added back to the class as a new or duplicate entry  
x = oldMyclass[1]; 
//we change the data 
x.red= 0x54;
//we add it back 
oldMyclass.add(x);
```

All is good until we edit the data after adding it say we need to change another value.
We access the oldMyclass and select the proper item say its index is 2 but we only want to change the values of index 2

```
Myclass x =new Myclass();
x = oldMyclass[2]; 
x.red=soemvalue;
oldMyclass[2] = x;
```

This will change the red value of both index 1 and index 2. How can I break the chain between index 1 and index 2?

I think I might have over simplified this question let me know.

Thanks for any information.

Edit: Here is the copy method that I tried

```
public static Items.SavedItem Copy(Items.SavedItem old)
        {
            Items.SavedItem x = new Items.SavedItem();
            x.generator = old.generator;
            x.hireling_class = old.hireling_class;
            x.id = old.id;
            x.item_slot = old.item_slot;
            x.owner_entity_id = old.owner_entity_id;
            x.socket_id = old.socket_id;
            x.square_index = old.square_index;
            x.used_socket_count = old.used_socket_count;
            return x;
        }
```

Comment: I don't see any `List<T>` here. What are you asking?

Comment: assume oldMyclass is a list

Comment: I think the concept you are looking for is a `clone`. Maybe have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/78536/deep-cloning-objects-in-c-sharp

Comment: Your question is currently pretty unclear. It would be a lot simpler if you'd show a short but *complete* example which demonstrates the problem.

Comment: If `oldMyClass` is in fact `List<MyClass>`, then what you've done (at some point) is add the same item twice. That's the only reason you'd have the problem you are describing. There is no "link" between index 1 and index 2 unless they happen to both be the same object. Also, you don't need `new MyClass()` if you are just going to assign from your List. You should spend some time understanding how reference types work.

Comment: I tried clone and the issue still stands the fact that you add a new item to the class links it to the the existing item

Comment: @MattBurland if you look @ the fist code block I make the oldMyclass[1] to the new Myclass object make an edit then add it back as what I thought would be a new list item using oldMyclass.add(x); but apparently the 2 becomne linknd how can I unlink them

Comment: @CKY: No. You assigned the reference at `oldMyclass[1]` to a variable called `x`. You didn't remove it from the original list and, although you did create a new one, you immediately overwrote the reference with the reference from your collection. You then just added *the same object* back into the list (`List` does not stop you from adding duplicates, some collection types do). That's why `oldMyClass[2]` and `oldMyClass[1]` are the *same object*

Comment: yes so how do I break the chain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So let's say, for arguments sake, you have a class like this:

```
public MyClass
{
    public string Foo { get; set; }
}
```

And you have a collection

```
List<MyClass> myList = new List<MyClass>();
```

Now you create an instance of MyClass

```
MyClass obj1 = new MyClass() { Foo = "bar" };
```

Now if you do this:

```
myList.Add(obj1);
myList.Add(obj1);
```

You now have a list with TWO members, but they happen to be *the same* object. Whats stored in the list is a *reference* to the object you added, not the object itself. So `myList[0] == myList[1]`

Now if you did this:

```
MyClass item = myList[1];
```

And then:

```
item.Foo = "something else";
```

Both the item at index 1 and the item at index 0 will have 'Foo == "something else"' because they are *the same item*.

Another point that seems to be confusing you is this: myList has two items. If I do this:

```
MyClass item = myList[0];
```

myList *still* has two items. Indexing a collection doesn't remove it and because of that, there is no need to add the item back to the list. It's already there. All I've done is copy the *reference* from `myList` to a variable named `item`.

There are collections (`Stack` and `Queue` for example) that do work on the principle that you will remove items and (potentially) add them back, but `List` doesn't work that way.

So if you wanted to add multiple objects to `myList` you need to create multiple objects with the `new` keyword. For example:

```
List<MyClass> myList = new List<MyClass>();
MyClass obj1 = new MyClass() { Foo = "bar" };
myList.Add(obj1);
obj1 = new MyClass() { Foo = "something else" };    // Note: I've reused the variable, but this is a *new* object
myList.Add(obj1);
```

Or, if you don't need the new object assigned to a variable, you can simply if to:

```
List<MyClass> myList = new List<MyClass>();
myList.Add(new MyClass() { Foo = "a" });
myList.Add(new MyClass() { Foo = "b" });
```

Or even more compactly, you can exploit the collection initialization syntax and simply:

```
List<MyClass> myList = new List<MyClass>() 
{
    new MyClass() { Foo = "a" },
    new MyClass() { Foo = "b" }
}
```

If you want to copy an object from your list, then you need to copy each property (and if it contains other objects, you may need to copy them too). There are various ways to do this, `IClonable` or a copy constructor are examples, but it basically comes down to, at some point, doing something like this:

```
myCopy.Foo = myOriginal.Foo;
myCopy.Bar = myOriginal.Bar;
// repeat for all properties that you want to copy.
```

Now assuming that `Foo` and `Bar` aren't also reference types, you have a copy. If they are reference types, you have a copy, but `myCopy.Foo` and `myOriginal.Foo` are still pointing at the same object.

Comment: yes this is exactly what I'm looking at now how do I not reference it and actually create it as a new. some one vote this up for me

Comment: @CKY: what do you mean "create it as new"? If you want a new `MyClass` just `MyClass y = new MyClass()`, then set it's properties how ever you want and then add it to your collection with `myList.Add(y)`. If you wanted to *copy* another instance of `MyClass` then you need to clone the original which is simply a case of having a method that will copy each property from the old object to the new one.

Comment: i tried creating a copy of the old object but met the same issue

Comment: @CKY: How are you trying to create a copy? `MyClass item = myList[1];` is not making a copy.

Comment: @CKY: If any of your properties there are reference types themselves, then you've made a shallow copy, not a deep copy.

Comment: they are is there something that I can call i tried icloneable but got lost this why i came here but was unsure of how to ask this

Comment: obj1 = new MyClass() { Foo = "something else" }; I tried somehting like this but was meet with an error let me try it again and get you the error

Comment: thank you very much I know how to do this now. Its going to take a lot more code then what I was hoping for but the end result will be what I need